# Does benzene react with steam to create an alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, alcohols, hydrocarbons

Benzene has a molecular formula of $\ce{C6H6},$ right? Surely it has some alkene-like properties because of the double bonds, so can it undergo a hydration reaction to create alcohol?

Comment: Getting the double bonds in benzene to react like alkenes is possible, but also rather non-trivial, and steam will not do it.

Comment: At what temperature? Probably well above the critical point of both.

Comment: Benzene doesn't have double bonds. Each of the six carbon-carbon bonds is identical, somewhere *between* a single and a double bound.

Answer (score 10):

Strange as it may seem, benzene can be reacted with steam over a suitable catalyst [[1](https://doi.org/10/b38nrs)].  The result is a complete breakdown to simpler molecules like methane and carbon dioxide.  Typical conditions are 0.055 atm partial pressure benzene, 0.60 atm partial pressure steam, and 370 °C temperature.

The cited reference also considers the breakdown of alkylbenzenes with steam under similar conditions.

---

#### Reference

1. Masahiro Saito, Yoshio Sohda, Michiaki Tokuno, Yoshiro Morita, [Reactions of Benzene or Alkylbenzenes with Steam over a Silica-Supported Nickel Catalyst](https://doi.org/10/b38nrs), Bulletin of The Japan Petroleum Institute, **1972**, Volume 14, Issue 1, Pages 54-63.